# How can I apply independent CSS styles to each styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I wanted to make Header component
So, I made two components (Logo.jsx , Links.jsx) and those two files are styled-components.
[Logo.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV8Hh.png)

After that, I made a Header.jsx file like this.
[Header.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fhYr.png)

I want to put some margin 10px between  and .
But I can't handle the components in NH that Styled-Component.

I tried the following various attemps.

1. Give a className attribute to
2. Used the Logo component directly in NH's css.
3. Tried to get the 'dynamic' className of Logo component, but I didn't know how to get it.

So, my point is that. How can I handle the styled-components in another styled-components?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions as far as I can see - how to access another styled-component and how to add a gap between your children components.

To answer the first one, you can [refer another styled-component](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) by using `${Component}` given its already declared before. For example,

```
const NH = styled.div`
  ...
  ${Logo} {
    margin: 10px;
  }
`;
```

To access another component in css regardless whether it's a styled component or not, you can use class name or id.

Regarding second question, if you want to add a gap between your two flex items, you could use [`gap` css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap). It applies gap between the items in your flex container.

```
const NH = styled.div`
  display: flex; 
  gap: 10px;
  ...
`;
```

Hope this helps.